# I can not make Queues synchronization in c#

Tags: c#

I'm creating a game in c# using unity3d. It is something like "Traffic Mania" . I need to enqueue the cars in the queue and dequeue them when they cross the street.When I enqueue it, it works fine .. but when i dequeue it, I have this exception :

**"InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object"**

here is my code of the queues :

```
public Queue UD_queue;

public int score;

void Awake(){
    InitQueues();
        score = 0;
}


public void InitQueues(){
    DU_queue = new Queue();
    Debug.Log("queue initialized");
}

private Queue syncQ(Queue q){
    Queue sync_q = Queue.Synchronized(q);
    return sync_q;
}

public void DoEnqueue(GameObject go){
    lock(DU_queue)
        DU_queue.Enqueue(go);
}

public void DoDequeue(){
    lock(DU_queue)
        DU_queue.Dequeue();
        score +=500;
}
```

and in other class , I call the method DoEnqueue() and DoDequeue()

can anyone please tell me why the lock(){} doesn't work?

Comment: You obviously have multiple threads accessing this queue. Please post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Why not just use a ConcurrentQueue?

Comment: The simple explanation is that you called Dequeue() on an empty queue.  There's no evidence that you check that the queue is not empty before making the call.  The way you use the lock will certainly increase the odds for making this mistake.

Comment: thnxx :) I added the check .. it is fixed now

Comment: It's wise to use lock with braces, always.

Answer (score 1):

how about using [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx). You don't need to use any locks anymore on that.